# Telegram: Cannot send message/photo into a channel with Telegraf (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf, telegram-api

I would send a message on telegram channel with telegraf. I'v einvited the bot and put him admin.

I've tested with this code:

```
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
  // Explicit usage
  ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.message.chat.id, `Hello ${ctx.state.role}`)

  // Using context shortcut
  // ctx.reply(`Hello ${ctx.state.role}`)
})
bot.launch();
```

But it replies only if i wrote on private.
So why it doesn't work on a channel?
Than how can i send a message in that channel without a command? (For example with and interval?

I i try this one:

```
bot.use((ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.message)
})
```

when i use the bot on private chat (with him) it returns all the message data. On the channel i receive undefined

Answer (score 0):

In your case CTX have current chat info, if you want to send message to channel provide correct id as documented for [Telegraf sendMessage](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=sendmessage):

```
telegram.sendMessage(process.env.TELEGRAM_CHANNEL, ctx.message.text);
```

I am using a bot for a public channel, so in my case it's:

```
TELEGRAM_CHANNEL=@MY_PUBLIC_CHANNEL_NAME
```

The channel name is available in channel info settings `t.me/MY_PUBLIC_CHANNEL_NAME`